# Should I use JSON or multi-dimensional array for my JS data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-structures

I want to declare a constant array/JSON of data for airports. The data should be indexed by a string, which is an airport code.

Something like:

```
const AIRPORT_DATA = [
    ['EGLC',
      {'name' : 'London city', 
      'lat_long' : [51.5048, 0.0495], 
      'zoomOutParams' : 'lamin=48.40003249610685&lomin=-12.32666015625&lamax=54.41892996865827&lomax=12.436523437500002}'},
    ],
];
```

which shows data for a single airport, with the code `EGLC` (obviously, I will add more).

I would like to access it like `AIRPORT_DATA['EGLC'].name` or `AIRPORT_DATA['EGLC'].lat_long`, etc

However, as I have declared it, when I `console.table(AIRPORT_DATA);`, I get

[image]

which is an integer indexed array.

How ***should*** I be declaring this data so that I can index it by airport code? I don't expect to have more than a dozen airports. I may add a few fields of string or integer types to each, but nothing more complex.

Comment: Object literals and nested object literals?

Answer (score 1):

To acecss the data using `AIRPORT_DATA['EGLC']` you would need to use an object, not an array, so:

```js
const AIRPORT_DATA = {
  EGLC: {
      'name' : 'London city', 
      'lat_long' : [51.5048, 0.0495]
  }
}

console.log(AIRPORT_DATA['EGLC']);
console.log(AIRPORT_DATA['EGLC'].name);
```

Also worth  noting that this is not JSON, this is an object. JSON is a **string** notation. This isn't a string.